# How do I use the SVN WebDAV HTTP interface to get the history of one file

Tags: svn

There are some cryptic instructions at http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/notes/http-and-webdav/webdav-protocol that hint at the possibility of using the SVN WebDAV interface to query the history of a file. So what is the exact HTTP call that needs to be made to get the history of a single file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm posting the answer because this took a couple of hours of trial and error.

**URL**

```
http://svnrepo/reponame/trunk/subdirectory/file.txt
```

**HTTP VERB**

REPORT

**HTTP Headers**

Depth: 0

Content-Type: text/xml

**HTTP BODY**

```
<S:log-report xmlns:S="svn:">
        <S:start-revision>1</S:start-revision>
        <S:discover-changed-paths/>
        <S:path>/trunk/subdirectory/file.txt</S:path>
</S:log-report>
```

The response from this request is a history of a single file.